# Function problem, pre-university level

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function $f: R → [-10, +∞) / f(x) = \dfrac{14a-b}{a³(b+5)}x²+(2a-3b)x+(4a-b)$ is even and surjective. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are their real roots, then $|x_1|+|x_2|$ is equal to? Answer: 9

I have been preparing for two and a half months to take the entrance exam to my university last Friday, which I passed with the minimum qualification. This is one of the exercises I have been thinking about the last weeks and I have not been able to solve it, I don't even know where to start. What can I do with the fact that the function is even?

Comment: If $f$ is even, then $f(-x)=f(x)$. From this you can derive a relation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "I don't even know where to start" : What is the problem composer's intent?  What theorems, worked examples, or previously solved problems, that you have been exposed to, might be relevant?  See also [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @Gonçalo I had already tried to use the theorem that for an even function it is true that f(x) = f(-x) but ended up arriving at an identity that was true for any real number. For example, I tried f(0) = f(0).

Comment: It's not a theorem, it's a definition. Nonetheless, $f(-x)=f(x)$ must be true for any $x$, not just for $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- Since the quadratic function is even, the axis of symmetry is the $y$-axis, hence we know that $2a-3b=0$.
- Also, we are told that the function is surjective, hence we know the minimum value is $-10$, can you infer the value of $4a-b$?

Once we know $a$ and $b$, we know everything about the quadratic function.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it, I was forgetting about the effects of parameters A, B and C of the quadratic function.